# How to get J48 size and number of leaves

Tags: r, weka

If I build a J48 tree by:

```
library(RWeka)

fit <- J48(Species~., data=iris)
```

I get the following result:

```
> fit
J48 pruned tree
------------------

Petal.Width <= 0.6: setosa (50.0)
Petal.Width > 0.6
|   Petal.Width <= 1.7
|   |   Petal.Length <= 4.9: versicolor (48.0/1.0)
|   |   Petal.Length > 4.9
|   |   |   Petal.Width <= 1.5: virginica (3.0)
|   |   |   Petal.Width > 1.5: versicolor (3.0/1.0)
|   Petal.Width > 1.7: virginica (46.0/1.0)

Number of Leaves  :     5

Size of the tree :  9
```

I would like to get the `Number of Leaves` into a variable `N` (so `N` will get `5`) and the `Size of the tree` to `S` (so `S` will get `9`).

Is there a way to get this information directly from J48 tree?

Comment: this might also be something for the Data Science SO or Cross Validated since there may be a better option than the "mechanical" one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As previously pointed out by @LyzandeR it is not easy to do this on the `J48` object directly. Generally, the objects returned by the fitting functions in `RWeka` usually contain relatively few informations on the R side (e.g., only the call and the fitted predictions). The main ingredient is typically a reference to Java object built by Weka to which Weka's own methods can be applied on the Java side via `.jcall` and then returned in R.

However, for the `J48` trees it is easy to transform the information from the Java side into an R object for which standard functions and methods are available. The `partykit` package provides a coercion function that transforms `J48` trees into `constparty` objects (recursive partitions with constant fits in the leaves). Then methods like `length()`, `width()`, or `depth()` can be used to query the number of nodes, leaves, and the depth of the tree, respectively.

```
library("RWeka")
fit <- J48(Species ~ ., data = iris)
library("partykit")
p <- as.party(fit)
length(p)
## [1] 9
width(p)
## [1] 5
depth(p)
## [1] 4
```

Furthermore, `predict()`, `plot()`, `print()` and many other tools are available for the `party` object.

I would recommend using this approach over the text parsing suggested by @LyzandeR because the `as.party` conversion does not rely on potentially error-prone text computations. Instead, it internally calls Weka's own `graph` generator (via `.jcall`) and then parses this into the `constparty` structure.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly it looks like the output of `fit` is created within a `.jcall` function in `print.Weka_classifier` as it can be seen from `getAnywhere(print.Weka_classifier)`. This makes it more difficult (but not impossible) to extract values from the print output.

In order to store these two values you could do:

```
library(RWeka)

fit <- J48(Species~., data=iris)

#store the print output in a
a <- capture.output(fit)

> a
 [1] "J48 pruned tree"                                     "------------------"                                 
 [3] ""                                                    "Petal.Width <= 0.6: setosa (50.0)"                  
 [5] "Petal.Width > 0.6"                                   "|   Petal.Width <= 1.7"                             
 [7] "|   |   Petal.Length <= 4.9: versicolor (48.0/1.0)"  "|   |   Petal.Length > 4.9"                         
 [9] "|   |   |   Petal.Width <= 1.5: virginica (3.0)"     "|   |   |   Petal.Width > 1.5: versicolor (3.0/1.0)"
[11] "|   Petal.Width > 1.7: virginica (46.0/1.0)"         ""                                                   
[13] "Number of Leaves  : \t5"                              ""                                                   
[15] "Size of the tree : \t9"      

# get the output length, so that this can work for a tree
# with any size/number of leaves
out_length = length(a)

# then save the number from the fourth to last element to N
N <- as.numeric(gsub('\\D', '', a[out_length - 3]))

#then save the number from second to last element to S
S <- as.numeric(gsub('\\D', '', a[out_length - 1]))
```

And there you have it:

```
> N
[1] 5
> S
[1] 9
```

Comment: and this seems to be the least-burdened option as well since I can't figure out where `partykit` (you can convert J48 fitted object to partykit or party objects) would make the info easily accessible and converting to a DOT file and using igraph seems like overkill (at least to me).

Comment: @hrbrmstr I didn't even know that there was a package that does this. Good to know thanks. If you say that it is an overkill to do it however, I ll take your word for it :)

Comment: hrbrmstr, How can I get it using partykit?

Comment: I can post a proper answer tomorrow. The short version is: `p <- as.party(fit)` and then `length(p)` and `width(p)`.